# script calling in another script in cron not working

Tags: shell, unix

I have a script which when run manually/standalone it works fine. When set in CRON it doesn't give output/don't run. The script has a tool specific command, which is installed on the server. <\br>

The command file is at location /var/bin
The script is at location /tmp/mon

Answer (score 1):

Write the command in the cron script itself. There is no point is writing cron and command in different files, even it will slow down the processing speed.

Or

Read the command file first and make sure you are getting the required command in the cron script file. If its proper then use the command in cron.

Comment: Hi Suchi, I had mentioned the command itself in the cron script. Could this be a issue where cron environment is not familiar with the tool specific command.

Comment: Is it working now? It should not be an issue.. you might have done some thing wrong..